# why won't my custom css load with the enqueue method or any other method?

Tags: customization, css, templates

```php
<?php

function load_stylesheets(){
wp_register_style('sj', get_template_directory_uri() . "/sj.css", array(), 1.0, 'all');

wp_enqueue_style('sj');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_stylesheets');

?>
```

my custom css which is named `sj.css` is not being loaded, why? This is located in my function.php file.`

Comment: Edit your post. Remove everything and replace it with the code you are using to enqueue your css.

Comment: People will only be able to help you if you provide more code examples - so they can help you locate the problem in what you are using.

Comment: I posted the code...but it is not appearing?

Comment: @JCSMOOTH345 it didn't show because you didn't use the right formatting, code needs to be in a code block, questions here use markdown formatting. I edited the Q to fix this, but you've provided no information about where this code is located, or what happens on the fronntend ( a 404 in the dev console? PHP fatal? )

Comment: it will not load my css in my source code...one sec will post

Comment: Thats just it Tom...nothing happens....its not taking my css....I tried all methods

Comment: Where do you put that code? It should be in `functions.php`

Comment: its located in the functions.php file,

Comment: I get no error warning or anything saying that it does not take... when I view source code its simply just not there and my styles are not applied either. I have tried it both ways.

Comment: no console errors or warnings?

Comment: do you have any plugins installed and enabled?

Comment: no, this is a custom template I am trying to make, so no, no plugins are anything

Comment: just basic html, css code.

Comment: and I know its not working because my images do not appear when I try to load the css